# Removing Conditions without resolution

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, conditions

So, I am rereading the **God Machine Rules Update**. An issue I saw the last time I played with it was that there doesn't seem to be a mechanic for removing conditions without resolving them.

Lets say a character gains the `Swooning` condition, inflicted upon him by a NPC who got a exceptional success on a first-impressions Socialize roll. If he never meets that person again, he will be stuck with *swooning* forever, and while it will have no negative ongoing effects, it will stay on his character sheet. I'm kinda OK with this; conditions that are never resolved, but never do harm, can become like the scars on a old warrior.

However for a more harsh example (that I saw basically happen in play), a character had gained *Obsession*: "Discover supernatural activity in this rural community." Obsession is by default Persistent, but the rules say the storyteller may decide to make it a Temporary (i.e., normal) Condition. We were only briefly stopping though the community to get some information that we expected to send us overseas. (An expert had retired there). This condition was only expected to last that chapter, as the character with it was just going to investigate the usual places, and satisfy his ever-present belief that the supernatural is everywhere.
However, another PC kinda screwed up, and we ended up basically driven out of down by a pitchfork wielding mob.

(For reference, the *Obsessed* condition gives you 9-again to following with your obsession, but No-10-again on anything else. When it is Persistent, it also gives a beat each time you fail a obligation to follow your obsession.)

So this character was stuck with the Obsessed condition for the rest of the game (it was only a short one-story campaign), and by rules AFAICT would never again get 10-again.

I might have missed the ruling for escaping conditions without resolution.
If not the house rule, I proposed was:

> "With storyteller permission, the character may expend 1 beat to 'let go' of a condition that is unable to be resolved, and does not contribute to the narrative. When ending a condition this way, you do not gain a beat for resolving it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing implications in the Demon Rules that conditions can be assumed to end at end of Story (i.e., campaign arc) because it references certain conditions as "Not ending at end of story."

There is also the *wanted* condition that ends on its own after 24 hours, or can be resolved by being arrested. Looking at **Blood and Smoke**, on Jadasc's suggestion: it actually has a section specifically about this, on page 193:

> **Lingering Conditions** 
>   Conditions are designed as reminders that events 
>   that  happened earlier in the story have repercussions later. Usually,
>   Chekhov’s rifle applies — if you put the Condition on stage, it should
>   fire by the end. But storytelling games are slippery things,  and
>   sometimes a story thread represented by a Condition is  better to drop
>   for the sake of the ongoing narrative. For example, an emotional state
>   like Wanton might no longer be relevant to events in the game because
>   a long time has passed, or it might have been the result of a
>   conflict with a character you don’t care about anymore. In those
>   cases, it’s perfectly fine to just cross off the Condition. We
>   recommend awarding a Beat as if resolving it, but that’s at the
>   Storyteller’s discretion. We recommend doing this sparingly, but
>   bottom line: If a Condition doesn’t feel relevant to the story
>   anymore, just let it go.

Answer (score 3):

I've just acquired **Blood and Smoke** for **Vampire: The Requiem**, which has the same list of Conditions. It says that the resolution for Obsession is:

> The character *sheds or purges her fixation*.

Being run out of town seems like a perfectly good reason to "shed" or "purge" your Obsession with finding supernatural activity there. It doesn't look like it costs you anything; it just requires a roleplaying rationale, which you have. (Many of the other Conditions have similar resolutions.)